# Play local video file without file extension iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I want to know if there is a possible way of playing a LOCAL video file which does not have an extension (eg. ".mp4") using the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` API.

If I try to play a video file without an extension using that API, it won't play it.

Can I possibly use the file mime-type to notify the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` of the file type ?

Changing the player API is not an option at the moment.

Comment: If you know what type the video is, can't you just add an extension?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I just want it to be flexible. If the backend service decides to send videos in another format, I don't want to push another update to client.

Comment: That is bad design. Backend should be consistent with what they are sending. Front end must focus on delivery and user experience and not to worry about such things.

Comment: @GeneCode So, backend does send the mime-type. But on the client, i do not wish to keep a condition to choose an extension based on mime-type. eg (video/mpeg4). Changing the service to provide a file extension is the last resort i am looking for. Wanted to know if its possible to achieve it to set the mime-type in the player or something. On Android its not a problem.